# Comparing two columns with containing one column and an addition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I have an SQL table with a lot of rows. A column in this row is called Label.

The label is a combination of different numbers; example of this is

```
11-1234-1-1
or
11-1234-12-20
```

The first two positions are always a combination of 2 (11), after the first delimiter it is always 4 (1234). The third part of the label can be either 1 or 2 values (I.e it can be 1 or 12 or some other random nmr). The fourth part is random and ranging from 1-99

In this table, I also have the exact same values but in the fourth part it leads with 10 or 100 (so the fourth part receives 4 values).
Example of this is: `11-1234-12-1020`

`11-1234-12-20` and `11-1234-12-1020` are the same.
I want to find all these values where part B contains Part A.

The labels are found in the same column.

I have joined the columns with each other:

```
SELECT A.LABEL, B.LABEL
FROM TABLE A
JOIN TABLE B ON A.LABEL = B.LABEL
WHERE ??
```

What should my WHERE-clause be?
I have tried with LIKE and SUBSTRING but I'm missing getting values.

I.e.

```
WHERE A.LABEL LIKE SUBSTRING(B.LABEL,1,12) + '10' + '%'
```

Seeing I'm a beginner at this I'm kind of stuck. Help please :)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT A.LABEL, B.LABEL FROM TABLE A
 JOIN TABLE B ON
    CASE WHEN LEN(RIGHT(A.LABEL, CHARINDEX('-', reverse(A.LABEL))-1)) = 1
THEN
    STUFF(A.LABEL, LEN(A.LABEL) - CHARINDEX('-', reverse(A.LABEL))+1, 1, '-100') 
ELSE
    STUFF(A.LABEL, LEN(A.LABEL) - CHARINDEX('-', reverse(A.LABEL))+1, 1, '-10')
END = B.LABEL
```

So basically we find the last position of a `-` character in the string by reversing the string:

```
CHARINDEX('-', reverse(A.LABEL)
```

Then we insert either a 10 or a 100 at that point to compare with the other labels.

Comment: `11-1234-1 and 11-1234-1-12`  are not a match though. 
Maybe I was too unclear in my initial post. 
`11-1234-1-12 and 11-1234-1-1012` would be a match.
The first three parts will be the same. The fourth will differ with a leading 10 or 100.

Comment: @Nickemouse Yes I see now, does the 4th part always begin with 10 or 100?

Comment: Well no, one label can be `11-1111-1-62` and one could be and should match with `11-1111-1-1062`

Comment: @Nickemouse But in the secondary label is the 62 always prefixed with a 10 or 100?

Comment: The fourth part of the secondary label will be maximum 4 values. So yes, always with either 10 or 100.

Comment: @Nickemouse see my edits, not the nicest solution by any means, but it should work

Comment: This works partly. Can you give a tip on how to make sure the fourth part of the secondary label has the length 4?
`11-2222-3-4` and `11-2222-3-104` are not a match but `11-2222-3-1004` is a match.

Comment: @Nickemouse see my last edit, it checks the length of the last part and then adds a 10 or 100 as required

Comment: This works! Thank you :) Changed the `IS 1` to `= 1` - syntax error otherwise.

I actually managed it before you updated last edit with the help of a WHERE-clause. But your last post gave me some new thoughts. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it on the join - remember you are joining two independent sets (tables) and you want the intersection where your pattern matches.

```
SELECT A.LABEL, B.LABEL
FROM TABLE A
    INNER JOIN TABLE B ON B.LABEL LIKE A.LABEL + '%'
```

Cheers, T

Comment: Yes, but this will also give me everything that doesn't start with 10 or 100 in the fourth part of the secondary label.
I.e.
`11-2222-3-43` will match with `11-2222-3-4301`   which is not a match. 
`11-2222-3-1043` would be the match

Comment: Refine it down - it gets you part way then (and will use an index on Label if one exists - hint!), use that as the join and then in the WHERE work on the next bit - you could do a SUBSTRING( B.LABEL, 11, 2 ) = '10' OR SUBSTRING( B.LABEL, 11, 3 ) = '100'

Comment: Thank you for your pointers. I managed to solve it with another way, though I realized that my joining logic is wrong - so your pointer helped me (hence the up-vote).